# jQuery disable field if other field is '0' or null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields, `fee` and `currency`. **Already working:** my field `currency` is disabled if the user enters `0` in the field `fee`. **What I would like** is to have the field `currency` disabled *also* when the field `fee` is empty (which is sometimes the default value, but not always). My code so far:

```js
$("#fee").on('input', function() {
  var activeFee = (this.value === '0' || this.value === null ) ? true : false;
  $('#currency').prop('disabled', activeFee);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fee: <input id="fee"><br>
Currency: <input id="currency"><br>
```

Or: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zp9ug1m/)

The part of the code that does not work as I expected is:

```
(this.value === '0' || this.value === null )
```

How to make sure the field `currency` is disabled in both cases whether `fee` is '0' or empty (null)?

Comment: value can not be null so never going to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of the empty textbox is `''`, and not `null`. Also, you can trigger the event listener manually to apply the effect initially when your code runs.

```js
$("#fee")
  .on('input', function() {
    var activeFee = (this.value === '0' || this.value === '') ? true : false;
    $('#currency').prop('disabled', activeFee);
  })
  .trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fee: <input id="fee"><br> Currency: <input id="currency"><br>
```

Comment: you can directly assign `activeFee ` with `var activeFee = (this.value === '0' || this.value === '')`. No need to make it ternary. It will already return `true` or `false`. Also you can minimize your code by `$('#currency').prop('disabled', (this.value === '0' || this.value === ''));`

Comment: @Karan -- thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to make minimal changes so that OP can clearly understand the difference between the original code and my code. Optimizations can surely be done, but after making the code correct.

Comment: Works great, thx! @Karan, thank you too for your explanation and suggestion.